# How many different possible remainders of a square number modulo an odd prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Here is a solution to the question:

[image]

I get it up to 'This means that either x-y = 0 ...' Beyond that, I am very confused. I was wondering if someone more experienced could clarify the remaining solution/explain it in simpler terms, if that is possible, please? For example:

I don't get what it means when it says:

- We get the same remainder if x and y have the same value mod p
- The only way these can give the same remainder is when they add to a multiple of p...
- This pairs the remainder x with p-x

And so on...
Apologies if my question is too vague - I'm just quite stuck on this and would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: When in doubt, work with examples. Here consider $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2 \mod 5$.

Comment: Okay @cosmo5 - so that would give remainders 1, 4, 4, 1 and 0... I see how that fits into the given solution in terms of 'pairing up' etc...But I still don't understand the general case - i.e. why this pattern occurs...

Comment: Hmmm...Sorry @cosmo5 - I still don't get that fourth paragraph in the solution given above...

Comment: I've added explanation in my answer. Please see.

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks @cosmo5 - just one final thing: How does the factorisation (x-y)(x+y) = 0 (mod p) tell us that 'the only way these can give the same remainder when squared, is when they add to a multiple of p'...? Also, why are the pairs x and p-x distinct, EXCEPT for when p-x = x (mod p)? What does this actually mean. Thank you for your help so far. I think I'm starting to understand.

Comment: $1$ and $4$ are *two* distinct primitive remainders. But $5$ and $0$ are same modulo $p$. $0\equiv (5-0) \pmod 5$.

Comment: Okay. And - How does the factorisation (x-y)(x+y) = 0 (mod p) tell us that 'the only way these can give the same remainder when squared, is when they add to a multiple of p'...?

Comment: $x-y \equiv 0$ means $x$ and $y$ both give same remainder eg, both give 1. $x+y \equiv 0$ means remainders are $x$ and $p-x$ eg, 1 and 4. $x+y$ and $x-y$ are coprime in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a numerical example. $p=5$.

We have

- $4\equiv -1 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 4^2\equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod 5$
- $3\equiv -2 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow 3^2\equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 2^2 \pmod 5$
- $5\equiv 0 \pmod 5\Rightarrow 5^2\equiv 0 \pmod 5$

The primitive remainders modulo $p$ are $\{ 0,1,2,3,\ldots,p-2,p-1 \}$ which are also $\{ 0,1,2,3,\ldots,-2,-1 \}$ modulo $p$. These are $p$ in total.

Squaring these we obtain distinct remainders $\{ 0,1^2,2^2,3^2,\ldots,(\frac{p-1}{2})^2 \} $ modulo $p$.

Thus we obtain $\frac{p-1}{2}$ pairs $\{(1,p-1), (2,p-2), \ldots\}$ (each pair summing to $p$) and a single distinct remainder, $0$.